# Google BigQuery: TABLE_QUERY AND TABLE_DATE_RANGE

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Big Query tables like below, and like to issue a query to the tables marked `<=`.

```
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170320
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170321
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170322 <=
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170323 <=
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170324 <=
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170325
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170320
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170321
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170322 <=
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170323 <=
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170324 <=
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170325
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170320
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170321
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170322
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170323
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170324
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170325
```

I made a query as this

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (TABLE_QUERY(mydataset, 
    'table_id CONTAINS "prefix" AND 
    (table_id CONTAINS "AAAAAA" OR table_id CONTAINS "BBBBBB")' )
   AND
   TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydataset.prefix, TIMESTAMP('2017-03-22'), TIMESTAMP('2017-03-24')))
```

I got this error.

```
Error: Encountered " "AND" "AND "" at line 5, column 4. Was expecting: ")" ...
```

Does anybody has ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix TABLE_QUERY and TABLE_DATE_RANGE for exactly same FROM!

Try something like below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM (TABLE_QUERY(mydataset, 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, "prefix_[AB]{7}_2017032[234]")'))
```

Consider [`Migrating to BigQuery Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

In this case you can [`Query Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)

See [`How to Migrate from TABLE_QUERY() to _TABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#the_table_query_function)

I think, in this case your query can look like

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `mydataset.prefix_*`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '[AB]{7}_2017032[234]')
```

> I can not migrate to Standard SQL because ...
>   If I would like to search for example between 2017-03-29 and 2017-04-02, do you have any smart SQL

Try below version

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM (TABLE_QUERY(mydataset, 
    'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"prefix_[AB]{7}_(\d){8}") AND 
    RIGHT(table_id, 8) BETWEEN "20170329" AND "20170402"'))
```

Of course yo can adjust above to use whatever exactly logic yo need to apply!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can not migrate to Standard SQL because I have to use PERCENTILE_DISC function which is not supported in Standard SQL.  If I would like to search for example between 2017-03-29 and 2017-04-02, do you have any smart SQL?

Comment: i think I answered exactly your original question. and still with legacy sql. yes i do have smart sql for your next question but format of comments does not allow me to put it here. Please accept and vote for this answer and then ask new question and I will be more than happy to answer it again

Comment: @N.F. - see update in my answer. Please consider voting up the answer. This keep us motivated to answer your questions :o) please consider!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is exactly I wanted. I slightly modified your last SQL to avoid error.