# Google BigQuery: SELECT only from newest tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Big Query tables like below, and like to issue a query to the newest tables for each group (marked `<=`)

```
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170329012345
             :
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170413032333
prefix_AAAAAAA_20170413112205 <=
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170327233456
             :
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170414012244
prefix_BBBBBBB_20170414130509 <=
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170327154412
             :
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170414090022
prefix_CCCCCCC_20170414091530 <=
```

like [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245845/google-bigquery-table-query-and-table-date-range), I tried to use `TABLE_QUERY`. But I could not find the way.

How can I do this? Or Can I do this with wildcard table in Standard SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.prefix_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (
  SELECT SUBSTR(CONCAT(t, d), LENGTH('prefix_') + 1) AS tbl
  FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTR(table_id, 1, LENGTH(table_id) - 14) AS t, MAX(SUBSTR(table_id, -14)) AS d
    FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.__TABLES__`
    WHERE SUBSTR(table_id, 1, LENGTH('prefix_')) = 'prefix_' AND LENGTH(table_id) > 14
    GROUP BY t
  )
)
```

Note: number 14 in above query comes from length of datetime related suffix in your tables

prefix_AAAAAAA_**20170329012345**